# iframe showing report inside Lightning Component

Tags: lightning, custom-reports

I have a Lightning Component which has an iframe.  The src of the iframe is the URL of a report to which a "fv" parameter is passed.  The component is within an Account Lightning page, on a tab which is not the first tab in the display.  The issue is that as soon as the Lightning page for the Account loads, it redirects the whole page to the src of the iframe. I want the report (associated with the URL of the iframe src) to display on the iframe when the tab is selected, I do not want the report to replace the whole page.  How can this be done?

Here's the code for the component:

```
<aura:component implements="force:lightningQuickAction,force:hasRecordId,force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,force:hasSObjectName" access="global" >
<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="recId" type="String"/>

     <iframe aura:id="vfFrame" src="{!'/lightning/r/Report/00O23000000GyO3EAK/view?fv4='+v.recId}" />
</aura:component>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it appears that this cannot really be done in Lightning.  We did find a few alternatives to embedding a report in Lightning which uses filters.

- Use the Einstein Analytics Dashboard lightning component (https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=bi_embed_lightning.htm&type=5) to embed the report.  This allows filters to be set.
- Use the analytics:reportChart visualforce tag (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_analytics_reportChart.htm) to create a VF page, which can then be placed directly on a Lightning page.  This allows filters to be set.
- Re-structure the data so that a report type, and hence a report, can be created which can be used in a Report Chart lightning component.

Comment: Einstein Analytics Dashboard lightning components cannot be used for standard dashboards.